# z-index not behaving as i'd expect

Tags: html, css, z-index

so i've got this, roughly:

```
<div id="A">
    <ul>
        <li id="B">foo</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="C">
    ...
</div>
```

These are positioned so that B and C overlap.

A has a `z-index` of `90`, B has a `z-index` of `92`, and C has a `z-index` of `91`. But C shows up in front of B. What am i doing wrong? (Let me know if more detail is necessary.)

Comment: Can you please post the stylesheet you are using?

Comment: Thanks for breaking down your question into a simple, generic case. That made the answer more enlightening. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `z-index` is only relevant for elements in the same container.  Since B is contained inside A, B's z-index will only apply when resolving other elements inside A.  As far as C is concerned, both B and A are rendered at z-index 90.  However if C is placed inside A, then B will render in front.

Answer (score 1):

If an element has no position:relative / position:absolute / position:fixed style, it's position:static which is the default position style for all elements.

**With an element who is position:static, z-index simply doesn't work.** The browser would render the stack in the order of xml element and ignore z-index property.

For a situation like this to work, you have to add position:relative to all 3 elements, A, B, C.

To understand more about z-index and CSS stacking, head to here: http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp