# z-index on safari mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile-safari

I'm making a webapplication. When I show an overlay, it covers my whole screen, even elements with bigger z-index. When I console.log the z-indexes, overlay is 20 and content is 80.

Now, the div I want in front is nested in an other div. Could this may be the problem? It works in all browsers (FF,safari,chrome), except in mobile safari (iPhone).

```
<body>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="content">
 <div id="thisInFront"></div>
</div>
</body>

$("#overlay").fadeIn();
$("#thisInFront").animate({"top":"60%"},1000);
```

Is there a way to get that DIV in front? Or do I have to nest my DIVs otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works on iOS Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/E8yyH/

Elements default to `position: static`. In order for z-index to apply, you need to pull the element out of the static page with something like: `#thisInFront {position: relative}`. The jsfiddle example shows a fixed position `#overlay` covering the entire viewport with `#thisInFront` raised above it. Verified on iOS Safari 6.0 on an iPhone 4S.

[image: screenshot of jsfiddle]

[W3cschools.com defines static position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) as: "Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow"

Check out the question, [z-index not behaving as i'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389788/z-index-not-behaving-as-id-expect). This doesn't have an overlay, but the same rules apply.